# How to send Base64 String as a parameter to api

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-volley

i am working on a android project where i have to send a base64 converted image string to server and retrive but in my case the url is like below

[image]

i am able to convert the string but the string is too big and i am unable to pass that big string into the url. Is there any way i can pass this string to url as parameter?

Comment: `but the string is too big`. How do you know? But indeed ithe query string  will be too long. I suppose you should execute a POST request instead of a GET which you do now. Look at the server documentation.

Comment: I am using AsyncTask and how can i make it a post method?

Comment: @DivakarLuffy I think that sending an Base64 encoded image to server needs to be send as a body parameters in a POST request. and yes as greenapps said, review server docs !

Comment: @Divakar you can send HttpPost request in asynctask as well, the same way as you are sending the GET request.

Comment: Is your problem solved?? @DivakarLuffy